# In Ardor, can you send a message with ZERO ignis balance on a brand new account that has never made a transaction before?

Tags: ardor, message

I know bundlers can bundle zero fee transactions, but can an Ardor account that is newly created without ever making a transaction send out a message and have it bundled? Or is this not possible as the new account never made a transaction before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From riker in slack:

The ability to submit a transaction with 0 fee from a new account is currently blocked by several layers of protection inherited from NXT:

1. The wallet does not allow it.
2. The API layer requires that the transaction passphrase belongs to an account which is registered on the blockchain.
3. The node logic requires an existing account to check the account balance.

It is enough to send a message or set an Account Property to a new account in order to allow it to send 0 fee transactions.